# PublicClientApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for WithUseCorporateNetwork

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-6.0, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

So I was upgrading my **UWP** solution to **WindowsAppSDK** and **Winui3** when I noticed this error that **Microsoft.Identity.Client** doesnt seem to have **WithUseCorporateNetwork** method anymore in the build pipeline of **PublicClientApplicationBuilder** which produces the following error :

> PublicClientApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for WithUseCorporateNetwork

[image]

I have tried multiple versions like **4.42.0** and **4.46.0** but they dont work.

The project containing this code is a WINUI3/WindowsAppSDK **class library**, based on **Dotnet 6**

Comment: It's not strictly related to WinUI3, this option is only available with UWP builds (see the WINDOWS_APP define condition here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/main/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/AppConfig/PublicClientApplicationBuilder.cs#L205). It was related to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationoptions?view=winrt-22621#fields (UseCorporateNetwork) which is not available for regular desktop applications.

Comment: @SimonMourier so you mean this feature is only available in uwp and not in windowsAppSDK and winui3 windows desktop projects?

Comment: "This option is only available with UWP builds".